# CSS multiple backgrounds can't be aligned to a relative sized <div>

Tags: css

I cannot find a way to align more than 3 CSS backgrounds of relative sizes without them overlapping.

When I create 4 backgrounds with 25% size each, I expected to position one at 0%, one at 25%, one at 50% and one at 75% resulting in a div that is 100% filled. But the behavior seems to be to anchor the last background to its right side, the first to its left and the rest of the backgrounds anchor to their center.

Correctly positioning a center anchored background requires it to be placed at 33.333(repeating)% which naturally means there is rounding by the browser, causing overlap, that results in dark lines where 2 transparent backgrounds overlap.

```css
.multi-gradiant-background {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center bottom, rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 70%), radial-gradient(ellipse at center bottom, rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 70%), radial-gradient(ellipse at center bottom, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 70%), radial-gradient(ellipse at center bottom, rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 70%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 25% 100%, 25% 100%, 25% 100%, 25% 100%;
  background-position: 0% top, 25% center, 50% center, 100% center;
  background-clip: border-box, border-box, border-box, border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="multi-gradiant-background">

</div>
```

Here is a simple fiddle to demonstrate the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/8jpwgous/1/ setting the positions to 33.33% and 66.66% might work on some screens, but fiddle with the size of the browser window enough and rounding will cause dark lines to appear.

While the example could be solved by placing two 50% width divs with two backgrounds on each, the practical thing I want to use this for actually needs 7 backgrounds to align, which unfortunately doesn't easily breakdown into equal groups of 2 or 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue can be solved by putting each background into a separate div and then using display: flex to align those divs without visible rounding issues.

```css
  .multi-gradiant-lights {
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: stretch;
}

.shadow1,
.shadow2,
.shadow3,
.shadow4 {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    height: 100%;
}

.light1,
.light2,
.light3 {
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center bottom, rgba(224, 213, 47, 0.5) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 70%);
    background-size: 100% 120%;
    background-position: center bottom;
    height: 100%;
    flex: 1 1 15%;
}

.shadow1 {
    flex: 1 1 2%;
}

.shadow2 {
    flex: 1 1 6%;
}

.shadow3 {
    flex: 1 1 6%;
}

.shadow4 {
    flex: 0 1 35%;
}
```

```html
<div class="multi-gradiant-lights">
    <div class="shadow1"></div>
    <div class="light1"></div>
    <div class="shadow2"></div>
    <div class="light2"></div>
    <div class="shadow3"></div>
    <div class="light3"></div>
    <div class="shadow4"></div>
</div>
```

I still find it highly unusual that the CSS properties relating to multiple backgrounds do not have a "all horizontal positions calculated from top right corner" setting. It makes gaps/overlap impossible to avoid.

But the issue can be solved using other methods.